# BackboneJS iterate through model

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Earlier my Backbone composite Model looked like

```
var ScenarioRecruitmentInfo = BaseModel.extend({
        defaults: {
            "partnersPersonalInfo": null
        },
        _parse: function(model) {
            return {
                "partnersPersonalInfo": new PersonalInfoCollection(model.partnersPersonalInfo)
            };
        }
```

PersonalInfo model corresponded to UI attributes on my view and I could dynamically select any attribute within my composite model

```
self.model.get("partnersPersonalInfo").each(function(model) {
    currModel = model.get($(target).attr('data-model-id'));
});
```

self.model is an instance of ScenarioRecruitmentInfo

But now my Backbone composite Model has changed to;

```
var ScenarioPersonalInfo = BaseModel.extend({
defaults: {
    "partnersPersonalInfo": null
},
_parse: function(model) {

    return {
        "partnersPersonalInfo": scenarioPartnerPersonalInfos
    };
}
```

so partnersPersonalInfo is a collection of the below model now;

```
var ScenarioPartnerPersonalInfo = BaseModel.extend({
    idAttribute     :   "scenarioPartnerId",

    urlRoot         :   null,
    defaults : {
        "scenarioPartner"   : null,
        "PersonalInfo"   : null  
    }
});
```

So as you can see, I now want to iterate and access an attribute which is inside my partnersPersonalInfo

My question is how do I alter the code to access the model attribute (which is kind of inside partnersPersonalInfo.PersonalInfo);

```
self.model.get("partnersPersonalInfo").each(function(model) {
    currModel = model.get($(target).attr('data-model-id'));
});
```